# How to add transitions to a slideshow using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow, transition

I have the following very simple Javasript code that changes the image displayed by changing SRC. The functions nextpic() and prevpic() are executed when two buttons are pressed in the main HTML file.

```
var pics = [
    "http://dp.topcovers4fb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Child-Tomboy-Display-Picture.jpg",
    "http://assets.rollingstone.com/assets/images/gallery/420cddbf3f116072564ab58c05f4d5e9b31aa046.jpg",
    "http://imgfave-chat-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/image_cache/1292725000558109.jpeg", 
    "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41N1wi0htgL.jpg", 
    "http://readynutrition.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/goat.jpg", 
    "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31600000/Random-Stuff-3-random-31692057-500-500.jpg"
]

function init(){
    interval;
}

onload = init;

var interval = setInterval(nextpic, 5000);

var max_pics = pics.length - 1;
var i = 1;

function nextpic(pic){
    var pic = document.getElementById("picswap");

    pic.src = pics[i];
    if(i < max_pics){
        i++;
    }else{
        i = 0;
    }
}

function prevpic(pic)
{
    var pic = document.getElementById("picswap");
    pic.src = pics[i];
    console.log(i)
    if(i > 0){
        i--;
    }else{
        i = max_pics;
    }

}
```

Is there any way I can do a simple fade transition to the images? The answers to the questions that asked so far is not applicable with the style of my code. I understand that there might not be a way to directly detect src changes, but what could be a possible solution?

Comment: It probably doesn't have much bearing on the current problem, but you should also include the HTML markup.  Also, include any attempts you have made to make a transition effect.

Comment: The url threw a spam watch. fyi ... It is not like we enjoy messing with his array.

Comment: the url threw a spam watch? if its the images in the array, they are placeholders that i will be changing for local images later. sorry about that

Comment: We don't know. A rep 1 user comes in. There is a url with pattern matching, and bots squawk. So to me, you want people to go to that page. It is called spam.

Comment: Is there a placeholder that is good with the site that i can use than random URLs, and not be considered spam? Thanks for telling me about this, I'm a new user and did not know about this

Comment: To me you have a face book link to farm "likes". There are hundreds of  bots running on this site. They each have their own dataset that grows. Come up with something creative. Welcome to the Stack :p    .... even with a 3 year old account.

Comment: @Drew I think it's more likely that these images were just pulled from google.

Comment: OP, I'd recommend hosting the images on a secure host like imgur for testing purposes as odd SSL addresses can make people jumpy.

Comment: @Polyducks I am merely describing how a few of us got chased here to begin with (look at Rev1)

Comment: @Drew Oh, were you forwarded here from a chat?

Comment: yes I was .............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer:

**Firstly, visualising the slider**

To get two items to fade in, one over the other, you must have two elements. One for the next image and one for the previous image.

Imagine it like a pile of three cards.

On the bottom you have a card with the letter A.

In the middle you have a card with the letter B.

On the top you have a card with the letter C.

- C
- B
- A

Now we want to take card C from the top and put it on the bottom. So we pick it up, move it down the pile and put it under B and A.

- B
- A
- C

As soon as you start visualising it like a deck of physical cards it becomes easier to work with. Cards can either be a hidden card, a covering card or a covered card.

In the case above, C was a covering card (covering B).
B was a covered card (covered by C).
A was a hidden card (we don't see it at all when we move the cards).

After we move the cards, C became a hidden card (at the bottom of the deck), A became a covered card (covered by B) and B became a covering card.

Likewise the slides of your slider will cover and reveal each other.

When your user presses 'NEXT', you will have to load a picture into the 'covered' slide and slowly fade out the 'covering' slide. When that 'covering' slide fades out, you can move it to hidden. Then you can move the 'covered' slide to 'covering' and the next one down in the pile up to 'covered'.

Your slide-pile will look like this:

- covering
- covered
- hidden

Indeed, you can give these classes to your slides and apply CSS which changes the z-index of your slides.

**Secondly, the transitions:**

To change opacity of the covering slide, I'd recommend you apply classes to the elements and use CSS to change opacity from 1 to 0 using [a css transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition). Once the new class is applied, the transition will begin, giving you a smooth transition from one to the next.