# Smooth transition between each images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this slideshow on my project, but when changing between images it seems like very abrupt. In other words, I want it to change smoothly between them.

```
<div>
  <img class="mySlides" src="assets/img/big_logo_1.svg" max-width="100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="assets/img/big_logo_2.svg" max-width="100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="assets/img/big_logo_3.svg" max-width="100%">
</div>
```

```
.mySlides {display:none; max-width: 100%;}
```

```
var myIndex = 0;
          carousel();

          function carousel() {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
              x[i].style.display = "none";  
            }
            myIndex++;
            if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
            x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
            setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 3 seconds
          }
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35710808/how-to-add-transitions-to-a-slideshow-using-javascript) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* The animation code */
@keyframes example {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
.mySlides {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

Adding something like this will allow you to dictate how the images appear. In other words, look into css animations. Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 1):

Using css transition and images positioned in an absolute way, you can achieve it in a few tweaks of your code :

```
<div class="carousel">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?cat">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?dog">
</div>
```

```
.carousel{
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s opacity ease-in-out;
}
```

```
  padding: 0;
```

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.opacity = 1;
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 3 seconds
}
```

```css
.carousel {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s opacity ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?cat">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?dog">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it would help you.

```css
.logo-container {
    position: relative;
}
.bannerImg01 {
    animation: bannerImg01 15s infinite;
}
.bannerImg02 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: bannerImg02 15s infinite;
}
.bannerImg03 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: bannerImg03 15s infinite;
}

@keyframes bannerImg01 {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    20.833333% {opacity: 1;}
    33.333333% {opacity: 0;}
    87.5% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes bannerImg02 {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20.833333% {opacity: 0;}
    33.333333% {opacity: 1;}
    54.166666% {opacity: 1;}
    66.666666% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes bannerImg03 {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    54.166666% {opacity: 0;}
    66.666666% {opacity: 1;}
    87.5% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-container">
  <img class="bannerImg01" src="assets/img/big_logo_1.svg" max-width="100%">
  <img class="bannerImg02" src="assets/img/big_logo_2.svg" max-width="100%">
  <img class="bannerImg03" src="assets/img/big_logo_3.svg" max-width="100%">
</div>
```

Comment: do "deserve" an upvote you should add a sufficient explanation of your solution. Unexplained codelines as an anwser can be cosidered low quality even if they solve an issue. An unexplained anwser is hard to reproduce as it is hard to understand.

Comment: I understand. Img1 has the content of logo-container. And other two images are absolute. this motion will make logos to stay 3.33s and change during 1.66s.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the `display:block/none` use `opacity:0/1` and add a `transition:opacity 300ms ease` to get it smooth like so:

```css
    .mySlides {
      opacity:0; 
      max-width: 100%;
      transition:opacity 300ms ease
}
    .mySlides.active {opacity:1}
```

In javascript

```js
   var x = [...document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides")];
   var current = 0
    function carousel(){
      x.forEach(el=>el.classList.remove('active'))    
      current=current<x.length-1?current+1:0;
            x[current].classList.add('active');
    }
    setInterval(carousel,3000)
```